# How to display/merge Oracle tables in different schema

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access-2007, connection-string, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to merge tables(ConnTest1 - Table1, ConnTest2 - Table1, ConnTest3 - Table1) from different schema into one schema ConnTest1 in Oracle SQL Developer.

---

Below is my script :

```
CREATE  DATABASE LINK ONETWODBLINK
CONNECT TO user2 IDENTIFIED BY pass2
USING 'ConnTest2'; -- Need to provide connection string but I have given name of   schema/connection

CREATE  DATABASE LINK ONETHREEDBLINK 
CONNECT TO user3 IDENTIFIED BY pass3
USING 'ConnTest3';

Select * 
From     Table1                        -- for connection 1
Union all 
select    * 
from      Table1@ONETWODBLINK          -- for connection 2
union all 
select    * 
from      Table1@ONETHREEDBLINK;       --- for connection 3
```

Comment: And your question is?  Why is this tagged for Access when your code appears to be Oracle specific?

Comment: Because the connection is created from Access DB. This syntax is incorrect, i wanted to know what is going wrong. Ref link : http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_displaying_tables_schema_database_link.htm

Comment: What is the syntax error that you are getting?  Are you getting an Access error?  An Oracle error?  Something else?

Comment: The syntax you're trying to use is for Oracle DBs. It helps connect different ORACLE databases with each other. You cannot use this syntax in Access DB.

Comment: Since I have imported MS Access table in Oracle SQL Developer it should not be Access DB anymore? Correct me If I am wrong. Also what should be changed in the existing syntax to make it work for this db type. Thank in advance Justin and Multisync

Comment: As I understand, you imported a table into Oracle (it doesn't matter which was the source database). And now you want to merge different tables from different Oracle schemas in one Oracle database. Is it your case?

Comment: yes. @JustinCave ERROR                                                      SQL Error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.